# Field width with printf

Tags: java

I have a question regarding the following line: System.out.printf("%3s", "Test");

Why isn't the output "Tes" from my understanding the 3 before 's' meant three columns were reserved. For example when I do the following: System.out.printf("%3d", 1); it will print out "   1"

Comment: try `printf("'%-3s'", "Test");`

Comment: I think the 3 means how much padding will be printed so in you case the output is "___Test" where _ is a space

Comment: Here is a useful link http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The field width is how many characters for whole field, including content, so given that Test is longer than 3 there will be no padding. There are examples of this in the [JavaDoc for Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

If you used a wider field, then padding will be used, here with a field of 10, 6 spaces are added to make it up to 10

```
System.out.printf("%10s", "Test");
```

Output

```
      Test
1234567890
```

Also the documentation states

> The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the
>   output. If the length of the converted value is less than the width
>   then the output will be padded by '  ' ('\u0020') until the total
>   number of characters equals the width. The padding is on the left by
>   default. If the '-' flag is given, then the padding will be on the
>   right. If the width is not specified then there is no minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the rule for width in format specifiers

> If the string representation of the value does not fill the minimum
>   length, the field will be left-padded with spaces. If the converted
>   value exceeds the minimum length, however, the converted result will
>   not be truncated.

So your expectation to truncate the value is wrong. It is used only for padding.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

> **Width**
>
> The width is the *minimum* number of characters to be written to the output.

*(My emphasis)*

Answer (score 0):

The field width specified represents the minimum number of characters to output.

This may be helpful: http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf